# How to get a responsive element to snap to a grid?

Tags: html, css

I have a responsive *grid* of items, as below.

What I want to happen is that when the container changes size (based upon screen width), you don't see part of an *empty cell*. This can be done by either causing a parent container to not grow past the end of the last item in the row, by causing the parent element to snap to a grid (i.e. only grow every 50px), or some other method of adding *X* amount of empty cells so the grid is full. I can't find any working solution though.

The cells need to be a fixed height and width.

I've tried using various `display: flex;` and `display: grid;` methods to no avail.

JavaScript is not an option.

```css
.mid {
  background: url('http://via.placeholder.com/50/ff0000/ffffff?text=X') repeat;
  display: inline-block;
  font-size: 0;
  width: calc(100% - 20px);
  box-sizing: border-box;
  margin: 0 10px;
  position: relative;
}
.mid::before, .mid::after {
  background: #0000ff;
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  top: 0;
}
.mid::before {
  left: -10px;
  width: 10px;
}
.mid::after {
  right: -10px;
  width: 10px;
}
.slot {
  background: url('http://via.placeholder.com/50/00ff00/000000?text=Y');
  
  height: 50px;
  width: 50px;
  
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: top;
}
```

```html
<div class="mid">
  <div class="slot"></div>
  <div class="slot"></div>
  <div class="slot"></div>
  <div class="slot"></div>
  <div class="slot"></div>
  <div class="slot"></div>
  <div class="slot"></div>
  <div class="slot"></div>
  <div class="slot"></div>
  <div class="slot"></div>
  <div class="slot"></div>
  <div class="slot"></div>
  <div class="slot"></div>
  <div class="slot"></div>
  <div class="slot"></div>
</div>
```

EDIT: I saw the linked answer, however the accepted answer there is massively convoluted and comes with the caveat that the cells "*CANNOT be given positioning*", and unfortunately I'm wanting to absolutely position another element within it. Also, that question and answer was written in 2013. We're now in 2018. Things have changed, tech-wise, since then. A lot.

Comment: @sol See my edit.

Comment: Fair point.....